# Multiple Arrays, need to find Nested Array Position

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, nested

Well i have this slight issue in which i have multiple arrays as show in the image below. As you can see the first array @ pos 2&3 have arrays there!

What i need is:

- To find their respected position in that array
- Then to get the length of all the showing arrays leaving out the nested arrays.

[image]

This is the result of the below code, i was assuming that with this logic that the first instance of the lengths should be `2` rather than `4`

[image]

here is code that i['m currently trying to make work:

```
for (var n = 0; n < objCollection.length; n++) {

    //works out how many value circles are needed if the value nodes do not have an array in any given position    
    for (var i = 0; i < objCollection[n].getPropertyValues().length; i++) {

        if (objCollection[n].getPropertyValues()[i].constructor !== Array) {

            //get the length of all the arrays that do not have any nested arrays 
             console.log(objCollection[n].getPropertyValues().length);
        }
    }

}
```

**To add some context** `objCollection` is an array containing my own custom objects each object (in this instance there are 7) are things you're trying to describe I.E a person, each object then has a property such as HAIR and finally each property has a value such as brown.

In the image below those are the values of earlier defined properties to use the image as an example the property associated with 'greys Atatomy' is the Name of the Show property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the number of *non-Array* items in an *Array*?

```
var arr = ['a', [], 'b', []];

arr.filter(function (e) {return !Array.isArray(e);}).length;
// 2
```

Comment: To add something else how does on find which position those nested arrays were at?

Comment: the second argument passed to the function will be the index, you could add another paramter name, e.g. `i` after the parameter `e`, and do someting with it inside the function before the `return`